# Dynamically create TableRow in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow

I've been struggling to figure out how to do this. I want to launch my `CActivity` and I want a scrolling TableLayout to populate (Think scrolling Instagram feed). I want to design the XML for my TableRow and dynamically populate those objects. Currently my only object is `content`. How do I dynamically create TableRows and populate their objects?

I'm really struggling to reference the objects from TableRow.

```
<RelativeLayout 
tools:context="com.....CActivity">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    <TableLayout
        ...
        android:id="@+id/CTableLayout">
        <TableRow
            ...
            android:id="@+id/CTableRow">
            <TextView
                ...
                android:id="@+id/content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);

    this.data_array = new blahblah[]{a,b,c};
    TableLayout tl =(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.CTableLayout);
    for(int i = 0; i < this.data_array.length; i ++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.id.CTableRow, null);
        TextView content = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.content);
        content("IS THIS CONTENT");
        tr.addView(content);
        tr.setPadding(0,10,0,10);
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: recycler view may be what you're looking for?

Comment: This looks all wrong to me.  You new up a TableRow.  Then you inflate a TableRow, but you're not referencing an id of a layout resource to inflate (R.id.CTableRow is not an inflatable layout).  `content("IS THIS CONTENT")` shouldn't even compile.  I'm lost.

Comment: @DougStevenson It is wrong. I'm trying to figure out what the correct way to solve it is. How would you approach it?

Comment: There's a bunch of example of how to dynamically create views in Android  What you're doing is no different in a general sense.